# Allowing hyphenation line breaks only when hyphens are placed intentionally

Tags: xetex, hyphenation, cjk, xecjk, paracol

I am trying to typeset a document using XeTeX that uses Tâi-lô (Taiwanese romanization), which separates syllables in a word with hyphens, meaning hyphens are very common. I am also using the `paracol` package to show the corresponding Chinese characters. I want to allow hyphenation line breaks only when the words have hyphens and disallow any other hyphenation.

Here's an example of my problem. This code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setlength{\columnsep}{25pt}
\setCJKmainfont{MOESongUN}
\setCJKmonofont{TW-Sung-Ext-B}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

%avoid overfull hbox with narrow columns
\tolerance=400      
\hbadness=399   
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{1em}

\newcommand{\ver}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1 }\nolinebreak}
\newcommand{\ch}[1]{\lettrine[lines=3,nindent=0em]{#1 }{\ver{1}}}
\newcommand{\they}{\texttt{}}
\newcommand{\paral}[2]{
\begin{column*}#1\end{column*}
\begin{column}#2\end{column}}
\newcommand{\nt}[1]{\mbox{-{}-#1}}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.4}
\footnotelayout{m}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\paral{\ch{3}耶和華上帝所造山野一切的活物，蛇是比\they 較狡譎。蛇對婦人人講：「上帝敢有影講園內一切的樹恁攏毋通食嗎？」\ver{2}婦人人對蛇講：「園內樹裡的果子阮通食，\ver{3}只有園中央彼欉樹的果子，上帝捌講：『恁毋通食伊，也毋通摸，驚了會死。』」}{\ch{3}Iâ-hô-hua Siōng-tè sóo tsō suann-iá it-tshè ê ua̍h-mi̍h, tsuâ sī pí in khah káu-khiat. Tsuâ tuì hū-jîn-lâng kóng: ``Siōng-tè kám ū-iánn kóng hn̂g-lāi it-tshè ê tshiū lín lóng m̄-thang tsia̍h\nt{mah}?'' \ver{2}Hū-jîn-lâng tuì tsuâ kóng: ``Hn̂g-lāi tshiū\nt{lí} ê kué-tsí guán thang tsia̍h, \ver{3}tsí-ū hn̂g tiong-ng hit tsâng tshiū ê kué-tsí, Siōng-tè bat kóng: `Lín m̄-thang tsia̍h\nt{i}, iā m̄-thang bong, kiann-liáu ē sí.'\thinspace''}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image: output]

At the end of verse 2, the "tsia̍h" splits into "tsi-a̍h", which would be wrong. I've tried using `hyphenat`, but that suppresses all hyphenation line breaks, even the ones with intended hyphens, like "suann-iá" and "hū-jîn-lâng".

Is there a way to only hyphenate when the hyphens are placed intentionally and not create any new hyphenations?

(I've fixed this with `\setlength{\emergencystretch}{2em}`, but this wouldn't fix a problem that might appear later in the text.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. declare to be using the fake language hyphenation rules `nohyphenation`
2. set `\hyphenpenalty` to 10000, which disallows hyphenation except at explicit hyphens

In the code below I changed the font for the Chinese part; adding a definition for `\languageshorthands` is needed only if you follow method 1.

Once you have decided for a method, you can plug it into the definition of `\paral`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setlength{\columnsep}{25pt}
%\setCJKmainfont{MOESongUN}
%\setCJKmonofont{TW-Sung-Ext-B}
\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho Pro}
\setCJKmonofont{Hiragino Mincho Pro}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

%avoid overfull hbox with narrow columns
\tolerance=400      
\hbadness=399   
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{1em}

\newcommand{\ver}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1 }\nolinebreak}
\newcommand{\ch}[1]{\lettrine[lines=3,nindent=0em]{#1 }{\ver{1}}}
\newcommand{\they}{\texttt{}}
\newcommand{\paral}[2]{%
  \begin{column*}#1\end{column*}%
  \begin{column}#2\end{column}%
}
\newcommand{\nt}[1]{\mbox{-{}-#1}}

\providecommand{\languageshorthands}[1]{}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.4}
\footnotelayout{m}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\paral{\ch{3}耶和華上帝所造山野一切的活物，蛇是比\they 
較狡譎。蛇對婦人人講：「上帝敢有影講園內一切的樹恁攏毋通食嗎？」%
\ver{2}婦人人對蛇講：「園內樹裡的果子阮通食，\ver{3}只有園中央彼欉樹的果子，上帝捌講：%
『恁毋通食伊，也毋通摸，驚了會死。』」}{%
\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}%
\ch{3}Iâ-hô-hua 
Siōng-tè sóo tsō suann-iá it-tshè ê ua̍h-mi̍h, tsuâ sī pí in khah káu-khiat. Tsuâ tuì hū-jîn-lâng kóng: 
``Siōng-tè kám ū-iánn kóng hn̂g-lāi it-tshè ê tshiū lín lóng m̄-thang tsia̍h\nt{mah}?'' \ver{2}Hū-jîn-lâng 
tuì tsuâ kóng: ``Hn̂g-lāi tshiū\nt{lí} ê kué-tsí guán thang tsia̍h, \ver{3}tsí-ū hn̂g tiong-ng hit tsâng 
tshiū ê kué-tsí, Siōng-tè bat kóng: `Lín m̄-thang tsia̍h\nt{i}, iā m̄-thang bong, kiann-liáu ē 
sí.'\thinspace''}

\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\paral{\ch{3}耶和華上帝所造山野一切的活物，蛇是比\they 
較狡譎。蛇對婦人人講：「上帝敢有影講園內一切的樹恁攏毋通食嗎？」%
\ver{2}婦人人對蛇講：「園內樹裡的果子阮通食，\ver{3}只有園中央彼欉樹的果子，上帝捌講：%
『恁毋通食伊，也毋通摸，驚了會死。』」}{%
\hyphenpenalty10000
\ch{3}Iâ-hô-hua 
Siōng-tè sóo tsō suann-iá it-tshè ê ua̍h-mi̍h, tsuâ sī pí in khah káu-khiat. Tsuâ tuì hū-jîn-lâng kóng: 
``Siōng-tè kám ū-iánn kóng hn̂g-lāi it-tshè ê tshiū lín lóng m̄-thang tsia̍h\nt{mah}?'' \ver{2}Hū-jîn-lâng 
tuì tsuâ kóng: ``Hn̂g-lāi tshiū\nt{lí} ê kué-tsí guán thang tsia̍h, \ver{3}tsí-ū hn̂g tiong-ng hit tsâng 
tshiū ê kué-tsí, Siōng-tè bat kóng: `Lín m̄-thang tsia̍h\nt{i}, iā m̄-thang bong, kiann-liáu ē 
sí.'\thinspace''}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]